# Syntax error in a batch script when asking for user input (/P)

Tags: windows, batch-file, syntax-error, wmic

I've asked a couple of people what the issue is, and have walked away twice without a solution. I haven't played with batch much before, so it may be a simple mistake. The code is currently supposed to give a list of processes using wmic. Eventually, I'd like to set it up to kill processes (which I should be able to do fairly easily), but I have to get over this roadblock first.

```
@echo off
set getprocesslistlocal=wmic process get name,processid
set /P remotemachinecheck=Type the name of the remote machine to view processes of (or type local for local machine), and press Enter.
if %remotemachinecheck%==local
(
%getprocesslistlocal%
) else (
set remotemachine=%remotemachinecheck%
set /P remoteuser=Type the user name to access %remotemachine% with, then press Enter.
set /P remotepassword=[Type the password for %remoteuser% on %remotemachine%, then press Enter. Watch your back, it won't be hidden!
set getprocesslistremote=wmic /node %remotemachine% /user:%remoteuser% /password:%remotepass% process get name,processid
%getprocesslistremote%
)
echo End of list. Press any key to choose process to kill.
@echo off
pause>null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you do is comment out the `@echo off` (or change it to `@echo on`) so that you can *see* exactly which line is causing the error.

---

Second thing you should look at is the fact that *commands* are processed for substitutions before they're executed, not *lines.*

That means the entire `if ( ) else ( )` structure will have substitution done on it *before* the `remotemachine` variable is set, meaning it won't be set to what you want, when you want to use it.

For example, this code:

```
@echo off
set xyzzy=plugh
if a==a (
    set xyzzy=twisty
    echo %xyzzy%
)
```

will *not* output `twisty` as you may think, but instead gives you `plugh`.

You need to look into delayed expansion and the `!!` expansion operator:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set xyzzy=plugh
if a==a (
    set xyzzy=twisty
    echo !xyzzy!
)
endlocal
```

---

Third thing, and I suspect this is what's causing your immediate problem, move the `(` to the end of the `if` line:

```
if %remotemachinecheck%==local (
```

With the `(` on the following line, it generates an error like:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

but here's the tricky thing: it outputs that *before* the `if` line, which may lead you to believe the error is on the previous line, as per the following transcript (indenting the lines generated by the computer):

```
c:\pax> type qq1.cmd
    set q=w
    if a==a
    (
        echo yes
    )

c:\pax> qq1

    c>\pax> set q=w
    The syntax of the command is incorrect.

    c:\pax> if a==a

c:\pax> type qq2.cmd
    set q=w
    if a==a (
        echo yes
    )

c:\pax> qq2

    c>\pax> set q=w

    c:\pax> if a==a (echo equal )
    equal
```

Comment: or change `@echo off` to `@echo on`.

Comment: @user2033427, that's probably safer if a user has customised the command shell to make `echo off` the default (such as with `cmd /q`) but I've _never_ seen this in the wild. Still it's a valid option so I'll incorporate it into the answer.

Comment: Even when I've modified the code to use just `remotemachine` (no duplicated variables that change), I still have the issue, so I believe it's a something different. Though I do appreciate the heads-up on that, as it would clearly have been an issue as well.

Comment: @Epic: and, when you turned on the echo, which line exactly showed the problem?

Comment: I had turned off the echo previously, @paxdiablo. It informs me of a syntax error after it recieves input from `set /P remotemachine=Type the name of the remote machine to view processes of (or type local for local machine), and press Enter.`.

Comment: @Epic, see my update, it has to do with the placement of the `(` character. It needs to be at the end of the `if` line, not on its own separate line.

Comment: The "third thing" was indeed the issue. I didn't realize the placement was so particular. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Additionally, I hate to go off topic, but would you be able to explain why no input (simply hitting enter/return with no text) after the first `/p` acts as if I typed `local` and runs the `if` portion's `%getprocesslistlocal%` and not the `else`?

Comment: @Epic, that would have made more sense in another question but, if you just hit enter, it doesn't change the variable - it'll still have the value that was in it beforehand.